# Python Pandas split big table column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big table (4M lines and 20 columns). In one particular column I have a list like:

```
                                        8 
0       [key1=it, key3=domain, key6=0001]                                                                                              
1                             [key2=home]
2                [key4=pippo, key5=pluto]
```

given a list keys=[] of keys I'd like to replace in an efficient way column '8' with other columns, something like this:

```
       key1  key2    key3   key4  key5  key6
0        it  None  domain   None  None  0001
1      None  home    None   None  None  None
2      None  None    None  pippo pluto  None
```

Thank you!
I

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the problem of bad rows in this way, but it is a for loop:

```
        self.s = lambda x: x.split('=')

        self.rows = self.df.loc[:, 8].values.tolist()
        dictList8 = []
        for idx, self.r in enumerate(self.rows): 
            try:
                dictList8.append(dict(map(self.s, self.r)))
            except:
                dictList8.append({'skipped': 'True'})
                continue
        self.dfMod8 = pd.DataFrame(dictList8)
        del self.df[8]
```

Any ideas how to make it faster?

Answer (score 2):

```
s = lambda x: x.split('=')
rows = df.loc[:, 8].values.tolist()
pd.DataFrame([dict(map(s, r)) for r in rows])

  key1  key2    key3   key4   key5  key6
0   it   NaN  domain    NaN    NaN  0001
1  NaN  home     NaN    NaN    NaN   NaN
2  NaN   NaN     NaN  pippo  pluto   NaN
```

---

**Setup**

```
df = pd.Series([
        ['key1=it', 'key3=domain', 'key6=0001'],
        ['key2=home'],
        ['key4=pippo', 'key5=pluto']
    ]).to_frame(8)
```

Comment: Thank you!. There is a problem to handle the exception in pd.DataFrame([dict(map(s, r)) for r in rows]). In case of problem how can I skip and continue? The error is "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required".

Comment: You can put a `try`/`except` in a definition for `s`

Comment: Then you must have input that doesn't conform to your example.  Ask another question that includes that sample data.

Comment: I have solved like the problem of bad rows, skipping the row. But it is a for loop.